# Creating and loading a custom gem via bundler gives errors on rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I used bundler to create a basic structure for a gem. I then put in a simple hello world and tried to put the gem in my app's gemfile. When I try to restart the server, it fails:

Am I missing a step?

```
    bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
    from /Users/boristoet/Sites/regiowebsite/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/boristoet/Sites/regiowebsite/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /Users/boristoet/Sites/regiowebsite/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/boristoet/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/boristoet/Sites/regiowebsite/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I'd suggest putting a known gem in the gemfile, commenting out yours, and bundle install again. If it works, the problem is most likely with the gem. Maybe something simple, like a misspelled word.

Comment: Thanks, got it working. Any idea how I can make local changes to the gem that are respected in the app directly?

Comment: If you make changes to a gem, an external library, you won't be able to update the gem when its author adds a feature or fixes a bug. The practice is frowned upon for this reason. You can use decorators to modify behavior of a gem.

Comment: I'm not making changes to an existing gem, but trying to create my own.

Comment: problem is that the rails app that's using the gem is not respecting changes I made to the gem. So new code is not being reloaded and I need to bump the version and rerun bundle install. Looking for a more convenient way to have code being updated automatically.